# Windows Phone 8.0 C++ member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, initialization

Consider the following setup. I have a Windows Phone Project which imports a Windows Phone Runtime Component. This Component includes a static lib. The static lib is shared code which I use in multiple projects.

If I create the lib as a Windows Phone 8.1 static library everything works fine. When I try to create the library as a Windows Phone 8.0 Project my member initialization is not working. My member are defined as follows:

```
MyClass{
  private:
    bool _myMember = false;
}
```

Like I mentioned this is working fine for WP 8.1, but failing for WP 8.0. Following error message is printed by Visual Studio:

```
Error   77  error C2864: 'MyClass' : only static const integral data members can be 
initialized within a class  <MyPath>\MyClass.h  141 1   MyLib
```

I know that the inline Style of member initialization was added in C++11 and that Micosoft just recently added this feature. 
Does anyone have a clue if I can get this to work for a Windows Phone 8.0 Project? My lib is very large and it would be a very unsatisfying work to change all the initialisation.

Comment: One thought is to change the member from a simple bool to a custom type that has implicit conversions to / from bool and initializes itself to be false. Then you don't need to change any code anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, targeting phone 8.0 means you'll be using the v11 platform toolset. Thus you are using the VS2012 compiler which doesn't support this.

You *may* be able to compile your code as a static library using the v12 compiler from VS2013, and link that into a skeleton project targeting phone 8.0 though (modulo differences in the runtime libraries).

I have some anecdotal evidence its been successful the other way around (v11 compiled static library linked into v12 runtime component), but that library had mostly C code.

Comment: As it tours out. There seems to be no way to get it to work on WP 8.0. Hopefully WP 10 will get a wide adaption when it comes out so the issue no longer persists.